# Symfony controller only one function to edit/insert data (Best Practices)

Tags: symfony, controller

When i read some code from other developers, sometimes i see in controller one function update and another function for insert and sometimes i see developer who make only one function for edit and insert. that is best way to do this only one function or two ?

Comment: if you use symfony form type, you can use the same code for both, so it s useless to duplicate your code

Comment: Of course since insert and update are two distinct operations, you code is probably not being duplicated in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I write at least these 5 functions for each controller:

- Show
- Json List (for ajax)
- Update
- Delete

Grouping them would only serve to make the code less readable, without any benefit

Comment: he question was about combining update/insert operations, not all operations.

Answer (score 0):

The [Symfony demo](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo/) is here to show how use Symfony, and it follow best practices.

Take a look at [this controller](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo/blob/71ebca499c85138beb98d876c0edb7b831944818/src/Controller/Admin/BlogController.php). You should keep in mind that actions of controllers should be small and do one thing. Create specific actions will be easier to read/understand your code. So I would go for two.

Comment: I guess I'm really in stalking mode this morning.  Link only answers are frowned upon and neither of your links directly address the question.

Comment: Ok sorry, I explained a little bit more.